# Subversion, how can I get from a revision number to a branch?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Our code base has quite a few branches, is there any way I can be given a revision number and from that find which branch the revision number was in?

thanks
T

Comment: I doubt you could, because one revision may affect more than one branch. E.g. I can commit changes to several branches in one commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory, there need not be any connection between a revision number and a branch. One revision can, in fact, commit to many branches (and even tags) at the same time.

However, you can query the log for a certain revision and try to figure out the branch, and if the commits are well-behaved, you will get a decent result:

```
$ svn log -v -r 91871 # if in working copy
$ svn log -v -r 91871 https://192.0.0.32/repo # with repository URL
```

Answer (score 4):

> is there any way I can be given a revision number and from that find which branch the revision number was in?

No, in common sense - revisions in Subversion are **global**, per **repository** (i.e each revision fixes the state of all objects in all nodes of repository)

If your task is "identify, which part of tree was affected by revision N", you have, as @MPi wrote, use `svn log -q -v -r N` command and get log for the root of repository (i.e no pre-filter for revisions will be applied), piped to grep for extracting *only changed files*